# cannot invoke 'setScore' with an argument list of type '(Int)'

Tags: swift, watchkit, func, watchos

I'm quite new to working with Swift and have a problem:
I have two classes in my WatchKit App.

Class 1:

```
func setScore(inputScore: Int) {
    scoreLabel.setText(String(inputScore))
}
```

... and Class 2 should have access to this func:

```
var countNumber = 0
...

self.presentControllerWithName("scorePage", context: self)
            scorePage.setScore(countNumber)
```

But I always get an error: `cannot invoke 'setScore' with an argument list of type '(Int)'`

I don't know how to fix this and it would be great if anyone can help me :)
Thanks

Comment: Had you initialised previously the Class 2 class?

Comment: I have: `class class2: WKInterfaceController {...`

Comment: The "scorePage" var have been initialised correctly? can you access other class methods through it?

Comment: Sorry...the class 'scorePage' is initialized 'class scorePage: WKInterfaceController{ ...}' and contains the scoreLabel and the func 'setScore' ...there's only this method which I can't access

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I’m not sure what are you exactly trying to do but I believe you want to pass data from one WKInterfaceController to other WKInterfaceController, so you can use the context:

self.presentControllerWithName("scorePage", context: countNumber)

Once you are in the receiver WKInterfaceController you should receive the countNumber overriding the awakeWithContext: func (the context var should have the countNumber value now) and then you can set the score: 
self.setScore(context)

PS don't forget to "cast" the context value from AnyObject to int

Example using Obj-C and an NSNumber instead of int:

In the origin class:

```
[self pushControllerWithName:@"scorePage" context:countNumber];
```

in the destination class:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    if ([context isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSNumber *num = (NSNumber *)context;
       [self setScore:num];
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to help you with the few information that you are providing, why are you placing my answer as wrong?

Comment: sorry, so hope my answer help you

Comment: can you please post an example of the 'awakeWithContext' fun? This doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark....

Using `setXXX` as a function name in an class that inherits from an Objective-C class can be problematic because it looks like the setter for an Objective-C property.

In fact, I would refactor this to take advantage of Swift features e.g.

```
class MyClass
{
    var score: Int = 0
    {
        didSet
        {
            scoreLabel.setText(String(score))
        }
    }
    // everything else
}
```

And invoke like this

```
self.presentControllerWithName("scorePage", context: self)
scorePage.score = countNumber
```